# Reading a stream over HTTP with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

I am trying to build a web app to stream music. I use MongoDB to store the audio, a Node API to connect to the database and a Vuejs frontend. Below is the endpoint which streams the music, based on this article: https://medium.com/@richard534/uploading-streaming-audio-using-nodejs-express-mongodb-gridfs-b031a0bcb20f

```
trackRoute.get('/:trackID', (req, res) => {
    try {
        var trackID = new ObjectID(req.params.trackID);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid trackID in URL parameter. Must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters" });
    }
    res.set('content-type', 'audio/mp3');
    res.set('accept-ranges', 'bytes');

    let bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db, {
        bucketName: 'tracks'
    });

    let downloadStream = bucket.openDownloadStream(trackID);

    downloadStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        res.write(chunk);
    });

    downloadStream.on('error', () => {
        res.sendStatus(404);
    });

    downloadStream.on('end', () => {
        res.end();
    });
});
```

I tested it with Postman and it works there. I am trying to read the stream in my Vuejs application. I'm just not sure how to do it. I tried the following to test it:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:4343/api/track/6061c90b2658b9001e65311d';

http.get(url, function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (buf) {
        console.log(buf);
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log('ended');
    });
})
```

This does not work however. How should I go about reading it in the frontend?

Comment: For browsers you can/should use the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) API.

Comment: Will look into this, thanks